# Good LaTeX Markdown editor

Tags: editors, led-editor

Can you guys give an example for a good Markdown Editor which *supports LaTeX*?

It should be:

- **Be a good *WINDOWS* desktop offline alternative for "stackedit.io"**
- Has dual pane for edit | view output
- Support advanced **Maths and Chemistry** codes
- Free/Open source
- Simple to use
- Support inline pics or videos
- Good UI

In my own Internet research(!) , I have found some:

- Haroopad
- Markdown Plus

But none of them are as good or as simple as stackedit.io

Please recommend some...

Thanks in advance

---

> P.S. - This may seem to be a duplicate but it is not...I have seen a lot of different SE questions but none of the answers have satisfied me....So, i decided to simplify the question by stating exactly what i need and what i have found.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is really on topic for this site (MathJax as used on some of the other stackexchange sites is mostly off topic) In particular it's not clear what you want the editor to generate. A LaTeX document (which would bring it on topic) or an HTML+MathJax document? I don't know of any markdown based editors that generate latex documents so I am guessing you mean the latter?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No this is a topic for this SE as similar questions about editors have been asked before...I guess you can go to https://stackedit.io/ to look for what i am asking

Comment: Asking about editors for generating latex documents is on topic, but you are asking about editors to create HTML.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yeah my bad...should have stated that

Comment: @NeilRoy Maybe a better place for this question would be http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ If you want you can flag the question and ask the moderators to migrate it tho this site.

Comment: Does "desktop offline alternative" imply that it must not run offline in a browser?